# How to setup my robot framework develop environment without root priviledge?

Tags: python, installation, virtualenv, robotframework

I developed a robot framework project with PyCharm in my test VM and now want to migrate it to a develop host that I only have my own /home/ permission and cannot install any package(but can scp file to it), Would you please give me some idea to achieve it?

Comment: In develop sever, the IDE is eclipse and I installed robot framework plugin, but for the reason of  lack of necessary robot package, I cannot import my project

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the python packages and install only for your user, for example, with:

```
pip install --user./robotframework.whl
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I have no permission to install any package and the system have no pip tool installed.

Comment: Your setup would be too hard to manage. But, what is your major need? To use an IDE to write robot tests, or to run them? Because, you can still use your working IDE and then transfer the files and run. Also, what is the `necessary robot package`?